# Cannot change text of kivy/kivymd label

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

When I try to get change the text of a label in kivy/kivymd it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'TheApp' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

Here is part of the main.py for a minimal reproducible example:

```
class TheApp(MDApp):
    btstate = 0

    def voice_session_connec(self):
        
        if self.btstate == 0:
            self.ids.Main_button.text = "Stop"
            btstate = 1
            th = threading.Thread(target=voice_session)
            self.th.start()
        else:
            self.ids.Main_button.text = "Start"
            btstate = 0
            self.th.join()
```

.KV string:

```
MDFloatLayout:

    MDRoundFlatButton:
        id: Main_button
        text: "Start"
        text_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: app.voice_session_connec()
```

Hope you can figure this out but I am not good with kivy.

Comment: Have you defined the `root` widget. Try changing `self.ids` by `self.root.ids`. You may also have problem with the `Thread` 'th', shouldn't it be `self.th`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Submit your answer and I will mark it correct if you want.

Comment: It has worked, that's all. Happy to help.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. It seems that sometimes you are not giving any reference to some attributes, methods of your class `TheApp`, where they are originated from. This doesn't follow `OOP` structure and can cause some problem. Try `self.something` instead of `something` whenever it applies within the class. 2. There are some ready-to-use handy properties in `kivy`, try them. For example, set `btstate` to `NumericProperty(0)` instead of just 0. You can find more in the kivy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention `root`. Change `self.ids.Main_button.text` with `self.root.ids.Main_button.text` then it works